# Нужна помощь с отправкой POST запроса с помощью Retrofit 2

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]Нужно отправить такой запрос не могу разобраться как отправлять такие запросы, пробовал с помощью HashMap, постоянно вылезала ошибка 403|Forbidden

```
@POST("user/event")
    Call<CreateEvent> addEvent(@Header("token") String token, @Body HashMap<String, Object> parameters);
```

Это Json - который нужно отправить

```
{
    "name": "Test ",
    "info": "Test Meeting",
    "dates": [
        "2022-06-10",
        "2022-06-11",
        "2022-06-12"
    ],
    "tags": [
        "tag1",
        "tag2"
    ],
    "deadline": "2022-06-13",
    "users": [
        1
    ],
    "event_id": 1, 
    "packages": [
        {
            "name": "Base",
            "dates": [
                "2022-06-11",
                "2022-06-12",
                "2022-06-13"
            ],
            "chat_status": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Вот POJO

```
public class CreateEvent {

@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("info")
@Expose
private String info;
@SerializedName("dates")
@Expose
private List<String> dates = null;
@SerializedName("tags")
@Expose
private List<String> tags = null;
@SerializedName("deadline")
@Expose
private String deadline;
@SerializedName("users")
@Expose
private List<Integer> users = null;
@SerializedName("event_id")
@Expose
private Integer eventId;
@SerializedName("packages")
@Expose
private List<Package> packages = null;

public String getName() {
return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

public String getInfo() {
return info;
}

public void setInfo(String info) {
this.info = info;
}

public List<String> getDates() {
return dates;
}

public void setDates(List<String> dates) {
this.dates = dates;
}

public List<String> getTags() {
return tags;
}

public void setTags(List<String> tags) {
this.tags = tags;
}

public String getDeadline() {
return deadline;
}

public void setDeadline(String deadline) {
this.deadline = deadline;
}

public List<Integer> getUsers() {
return users;
}

public void setUsers(List<Integer> users) {
this.users = users;
}

public Integer getEventId() {
return eventId;
}

public void setEventId(Integer eventId) {
this.eventId = eventId;
}

public List<Package> getPackages() {
return packages;
}

public void setPackages(List<Package> packages) {
this.packages = packages;
}

}

----------------------------------------------------------------------

public class Package {

@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("dates")
@Expose
private List<String> dates = null;
@SerializedName("chat_status")
@Expose
private Boolean chatStatus;

public String getName() {
return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

public List<String> getDates() {
return dates;
}

public void setDates(List<String> dates) {
this.dates = dates;
}

public Boolean getChatStatus() {
return chatStatus;
}

public void setChatStatus(Boolean chatStatus) {
this.chatStatus = chatStatus;
}

}
```

Comment: 403 ошибка говорит о том, что скорее всего проблема с токеном. Убедитесь, что вы правильный токен правильно прикрепляете к запросу

Comment: @ЮрийСПб спасибо за помощь, проверю, но вы можете помочь как правильно отправлять такой запрос?

Comment: Отправляете, концептуально, правильно. Чем-то помочь можно только если знать как сервер запрос принимать желает. У вас есть к-л пример успешного запроса?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Насчет токена проверил никаких ошибок все верно, к-л что имеете ввиду?

Comment: Я имел в виду - есть ли пример успешного запроса. Курлом, через браузер (подсмотренный в консоли на сайте) или через что-то типа Postman? И попробуйте вместо мапы слать класс, описывающий структуру JSON (правда, судя по ошибке - дело таки в токене).

Comment: @ЮрийСПб да я через postman проверяю все работает, с токеном тоже все ок тоже самое все там прописываю работает, просто я не понимаючто не так, мы можем с какой-то Соц сети связаться чтобы подробно разобрать, конечно же если у вас есть время

Comment: Мне тут удобнее. Покажите как в Postman запрос выглядит

Comment: @ЮрийСПб добавил фото с postman

Comment: Покажите ещё что у вас в постман в заголовках. Возможно, вам надо добавить в Retrofit заголовок Content-Type аналогичный Postma-овскому. Возможно, сервер это хочет от вас. Ну и телом передавать лучше, кажется, не мапу, но класс.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Можете привести пример как правильно передавать класс(по json которую я указал)? Думаю проблема в этом

Comment: Проблема с вероятностью около 0% связана с типом передаваемого значения, но вот пример: `@POST("user/event")
    Call<CreateEvent> addEvent(@Header("token") String token, @Body CreateEvent parameters);`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб с этим у меня проблем нет, я кажется нашел ошибку я не правильно передаю даты, если не ошибаюсь я их должен передавать таким способом List<Date> dates = null (POJO). Может быть из-за этого?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб я щас вывел ошибку на экран через response.errorBody().string() и у меня вышла ошибка A token is required for authentication. Я не понимаю я же отправляю токен Call<CreateEvent1> call = getResponse.addEvent(Global.key, "Bearer" + token, createEvent1);

Comment: Мало отправить - нужно отправить так, как хочет сервер (см. его API-доки). Или посмотрите в постмане заголовки удачного **запроса** (не ответа). Если это стандартная авторизация по Bearer-токену, см. примеры здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41082979/15923106 (обратите внимание на имя заголовка и что между `Bearer` и токеном есть пробел)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб ну я также отправляю даже с пробелом попробовал не выходит

Comment: @АйдынАгаев, мне непонятно что это такое: `Call<CreateEvent1> call = getResponse.addEvent(Global.key, "Bearer" + token, createEvent1);` - у вас в вопросе у метода 2 аргумента, а тут - 3. Что в первом - неясно. Подключите логгирование запроса и покажите что именно вы в итоге на сервер отправляете. Хорошо, что вы убедились, что проблема - в том как отправляется токен. Если непонятно в чём дело - покажите как в постмане токен отправляется. Это либо во вкладке Authorization или во вкладке Headers. И покажите как вы

Comment: @ЮрийСПб у меня есть дополнительный Header - Authorization - 1ый параметр и я добавил изображение как отправляю

Comment: Вы, почему-то, упорно не хотите помочь вам помочь. Скорее всего, если бы вы сутки назад показали в Postman какие заголовки вы посылаете при успешном запросе мы смогли бы вам сказать что не так с вашим текущим запросом через Retrofit. Засим вот моё последнее, скорее всего верное предположение: вы неправильно указываете имя заголовка авторизации. Вы указали имя `token`, а надо - Authorization. И значением, как писали выше, скорее всего должно быть `Bearer ТУТ_ВАШ_ТОКЕН`. Но точно сказать нельзя, т.к. вы беспричинно не хотите показывать несколько раз запрошенные скрины Postman

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Я не понимаю какие заголовки вы хотите чтобы я показал, я новичок во всем этом и хочу разобраться, перерыл весь интернет не смог ничего найти. Наверху я прикрепил еще одно фото где Headers

Comment: Вот этот скриншот и был нужен) Вам надо, похоже, 2 заголовка прикрепить - Authorization и x-access-token. Т.е. должно примерно так выглядеть в Retrofit: `@POST("user/event")     Call<CreateEvent> addEvent(@Header("Authorization") String authorizationValue, @Header("x-access-token") String xAccessTokenValue, @Body CreateEvent parameters);` Передавать, соответственно, надо первым аргументом то, что у вас чёрным на скрине замазано, а вторым - то что незамазано напротив `x-access-token`.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб благодарю вас за помощь и за то-что измучил вас))) Все получилось НАКОНЕЦ!!! Последняя просьба заключается в том, можете ли вы мне посоветовать нормальную документацию по Retrofit где все описано на Русском или Английском без разницы. Спасибо за помощь!!!

Comment: Кроме официальной [доки](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) ничего на ум не приходит. Тут, скорее, нужно общее понимание того как работает связка клиент-сервер и как работает http протокол. Однако лично я не вижу смысла специально их изучать. В моей практике и практике людей которых знаю всё это само собой приходит с опытом.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Спасибо!!))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда вы получаете 403 ошибку - это значит, что сервер не смог распознать в запросе информацию об авторизации. Эту информацию передавать надо так, как того желает сервер. Обычно используют передачу данных в заголовках или в параметрах запроса. Важно внимательно смотреть на имена заголовков и на их зачения.

Вам надо 2 заголовка прикрепить - `Authorization` и `x-access-token`. Т.е. должно примерно так выглядеть в Retrofit:

```
@POST("user/event")
Call<CreateEvent> addEvent(@Header("Authorization") String authorizationValue, @Header("x-access-token") String xAccessTokenValue, @Body CreateEvent parameters);
```

Передавать, соответственно, надо первым аргументом то, что у вас чёрным на скрине замазано, а вторым - то что не замазано напротив x-access-token